# Turn off the [production-environment]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

How can one be an expert in [production-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/production-environment)?

Sure we all have them, but I feel that adding this tag to any question doesn't really add value. Regardless of where the problem is occurring, it's obviously a problem otherwise you wouldn't be posting on SO. The highest voted question is how you deploy a Ruby on Rails app to a production server.

A quick peruse of the tag itself reveals questions on everything from Ruby on Rails to *Nix to the Selenium Webdriver (Why anyone is trying to automate functional testing on a Prod environment is a bit beyond me)

At 700+ questions its a bit beyond me while procrastinating at work, but it still seems to be a meta-tag and not really adding any useful information to the question that it's tagging.

Thoughts?

Comment: You might want to take a peek at the other "environment"-tags...

Comment: Nice find! As @Deduplicator mentioned a few of the other environment tags should be removed also.

Comment: I love the titles people use on burninate posts, sometimes!

Comment: It's a nice set of questions to be closed. Most of them, from what I've seen, are primarily opinion based, too broad, code dumps or off topic.

Comment: I wonder who could even benefit by following this tag. Do we need to start going through them and flagging the bad questions. The good ones just remove the tag?

Comment: It is sometimes nice to know that the problem is in a production-environment, but I agree that it shouldn't be a tag. When that information affects the answers it should be part of the post.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I've just discovered that the [wife] tag is a thing.... Just imagine what one could do with that

Comment: Maybe if there is a production tag in Ruby on Rails, it can be changed to [rails-prod] or something.

Comment: I can't really decide either way about this; it might be useful in situations where (for example) a problem that occurs in a production environment cannot be reproduced in development/testing. I probably wouldn't tag my own Rails-related questions based on environment, but others might think differently.

Comment: I'm surprised to see this two-year old request still hanging around.  This tag *definitely* needs to catch fire.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, the tag is all over the place, and coupled with some more, umm... tags of suspicious usefulness development-environment (106) and deployment (69), is very evident it needs thorough burnination.